# Custom addToDisplay method returns exception in another class

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

A newcomer here. I am having trouble with a method that prints text into a `JTextArea`.

The `addToDisplay` method works fine in the native `GameWindow` class. Here it is:

```
public class GameWindow extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
    JTextArea displayArea;

    public GameWindow() {
        ...
        this.addToDisplay(""); //Works fine
    }
    public void addToDisplay(String newString) {
        displayArea.append("\n" + newString);
        displayArea.selectAll();
    }
}
```

When the method is called in another class of the same package, it throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

```
public class Duelist {
    private GameWindow window;

    public Duelist(String n) {
        ...
    }

    public void dueling(Duelist opponent) {
        ...
        window.addToDisplay(""); //Exception occurs here
    }
}
```

Please show me how to get rid of the exception. If you need more information, let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialize the `GameWindow` in the Duelist class before using

```
GameWindow window=new GameWindow();
```

For ex in your constructor or wherever you want before calling that methods

```
public Duelist(String n) {
    window=new GameWindow();
        ...
    }
```

Comment: +1 The constructor didn't work, but it helped me figure out how to initialize it. Thanks for the response!